# Load vector NEON intrinsics

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

I would like to load from memory vectors of 128 bits:
I've got these pointers:

```
int8x16_t* p1=(int8x16_t*)srcimg.data;
int8x16_t* p2=(int8x16_t*)(srcimg.data+srcimg.cols);
```

The problem is that the load function is this one:

```
int8x16_t vld1q_s8(__transfersize(16) int8_t const * ptr);
```

I don't understand why the function takes in input an int8_t* value.

I would like to do something like this:

```
int8x16_t vector;
vector=vld1q_s8(p1);
```

How can I do it?Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should already work like below.

```
int8x16_t vector;
vector=vld1q_s8((int8_t *) srcimg.data);
```

`int8x16_t` is a vector type, created to make it easy to read vector layout.

`int8_t` is what you would call a byte.

Reading it aloud should sound like "load into a quad register from this byte stream".

If you also check [gcc arm intrinsics page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html), you shouldn't be able to find any pointer to those vector types. They mean to map to `SIMD` registers, and you don't generally talk pointers to registers.

If you would like to get more information about neon programming you can check [ARM's website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0018a/index.html) and this [blog series](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/161-coding-for-neon-part-1-load-and-stores/).

Comment: It's not really clear to me the difference in doing : int8x16_t* p1=(int8x16_t*)srcimg.data;  and doing a cast with (int8_t *) srcimg.data like you said. I mean, in one case we are talking about a vector of 128 bit and in the other case about one byte.

Comment: @user2696208 and yet again all behavior is dependent on how `vld1q_s8` reads data.

Comment: What do you mean?How can I understand how it reads data?  I'm sorry but I'm new to NEON so a little bit more of explanation would be of help. Thank you. What I would like to do in the following part is a loop where I increment the value of the pointers p1 and p2 and in each cycle load vectors of 128 bit from the memory positions pointed by p1 and p2.